# Prove that $P(E \cap F^c) = P(E) - P(E \cap F)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove the equality $P(E \cap F^c) = P(E) - P(E \cap F)$, but I feel as if I'm going in circles after I wrote one of the probability axioms $P(E \cap F^c) = P(E) + P(F^c)-P(E \cup F^c)$.

Observing that we have $P(E)$ on both sides, I tried to prove that $-P(E\cap F) = P(F^c)-P(E\cup F^c)$, or better yet $P(E \cup F^c) = P(F^c)+P(E\cap F)$.

I used the probability axiom once again to achieve the equality $P(E \cup F^c) = P(E) + P(F^c) - P(E \cap F^c)$.

At this point, I feel lost since I think I'm going in circles. I tried to show that $P(E)-P(E\cap F^c) = P(E\cap F)$. However, I think it's only intuitively true when $E$ and $F$ are disjoint, which is not part of the assumption.

I thought this problem might have been easy since I'm pretty comfortable with elementary set theory, but the fact that these are real numbers between 0 and 1 is throwing me off. I'm not yet sure how to think about proving statements about probability, so intuition is especially appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the sets into mutually exclusive sets.

In this case $E = (E \cap F) \cup (E \setminus F)$
and the sets 
$E \cap F$, $E \setminus F$  are pairwise
disjoint.

Hence $P(E) = P(E \cap F) + P(E \setminus F)$.

Comment: This makes sense! Thanks. So then this only works when $E$ and $F$ are mutually exclusive?

Comment: No, $E,F$ are not necessarily mutually exclusive. The sets $E \cap F$, $E \setminus F$ are.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It was not me who downvoted your answer, so I am also curious.

Comment: No problem. I am just curious why someone would downvote this?

Comment: The set $E$ consists of points that are in $F$ (that is, $E \cap F$) and points that are not in $F$ (that is $E \setminus F = E \cap F^c$), and the probability of two disjoint events is the sum of the probabilities of each event.

Comment: That explanation made it click - many thanks. I realize now what you did in the original post. (Embarrassingly, I also forgot that $E-F = E\cap F^c$)

Comment: Glad to be able to help!